# Uploading images to a windows server using python

Tags: python, image, file-upload, windows-server

thanks in advance

I have a nginx server in which i am running python tornado application server. My tornado server conatins api endpoints(Handler), Models (DB table models) and the code for their respective services. We are using it as a backend service for an app that sells goods. Recently, we have implemented a complain feature that lets you upload image for the products.

I have to write code in python to convert base64 image into actual jpg/png (which is done), and then upload it to a different windows server(i m stuck in uploading part). I have been researching about it and found a few ways like

1. FTP
2. by RemoteDesktopConnection (it is clearly not for me)
3. and a few more.

if there is any better way to do this plz tell. i am not really experienced so plz explain your answers in a bit detail. Thank you for your time.

previously i was storing it in my application server which is clearly not a good thing to do and i was not able to expose the url for images also.

Comment: If your tornado application contains API endpoints then can't you use them to upload? python's requests library might help.

Comment: yes, you are right but my problem is i don't know how to upload that image to another windows server. FTP is one option but let's say we can not use it then what other options do i have ? that's my query.

Answer (score 0):

If it just needs to be a file in a directory on the other windows server, one could turn on file sharing for the specific directory on the other windows server and then smb mount that directory onto your application server.   Then your python code could simply write a file to that directory.

A fairly good guide for doing this can be found [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/176471/how-to-share-files-between-windows-and-linux/)

Note that in a final production environment you want to be sure that the security is set appropriately (which is beyond the scope of this question).

Comment: thanks for your response, but i don't understand what you mean by "smb mount that directory onto our application server". Currently my nginx server contains my application server and i am getting images in this nginx server via APIs. and What i want is to upload or send these image to another windows server. plz elaborate if you can.

Comment: @Yashverma  I've edited the answer to include a link to a nice how-to guide that explains this process in more detail.   Ask if you have further questions after reviewing that.